# How can you programatically create a receive location?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-ps1-provider

How can you programatically create a BizTalk receive location in PowerShell?

*And extending the question ...* receive ports and send ports

I've been using the BizTalk PowerShell provider, but unfortunately its `New-Item` method doesn't support these artefacts.

Comment: MSDN contains [an example of setting up a SOAP receive location programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561021.aspx). Should be easy to extend it to set up other types of receive locations (if you navigate around the different adapter types on MSDN you can see information about programmatically creating those too, as well as information about programmatically creating receive ports and send ports). That example uses .NET types which you can load and use in your PowerShell script.

Comment: @robert.westerlund Ah ha, the  page mentions the "BizTalk Explorer object model" ... and there is a section on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560198(v=bts.20).aspx and some samples in the SDK at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\SDK\Samples\Admin\ExplorerOM

Comment: @SteveC: would be nice to formulate an answer and mark it as answer then.

Comment: @ PieterVandenheede Will do ... once I get it working  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use explorerOM

```
[void] [System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM")
$server = "."
$connectionString = "SERVER=" + $server + ";DATABASE=BizTalkMgmtDb;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$Catalog = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
$Catalog.ConnectionString = $connectionString
```

You will have to add a new Application using "AddNewApplication"

```
$app = $Catalog.AddNewApplication()
$rcvPort = $app.AddNewReceivePort(0)
$rcvLocation = $rcvPort.AddNewReceiveLocation()
```

Define properties for the receive port and location.

Good Luck.